# how to rotate a view continuously at a constant speed?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to rotate a view continuously at a constant speed.
I have used,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <rotate

    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="1800"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="1000"
     />

  </set>
```

But after one rotation it pauses for a while, then starts another rotation. Is there any way to eliminate the pause?

Comment: add one more line `android:repeatMode="restart" android:toDegrees="360"`

Answer (score 2):

For continue use android:repeatMode="restart"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
    android:duration="1700"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />

   </set>
```

Comment: it rotates continuously, but there is a pause between two rotations.I want it not to stop before starting another rotation. is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your RotationAnimation and you will get what you need :-

```
rotate.setInterpolator(this, android.R.anim.linear_interpolator);
```

Or add this in your animation xml ;-

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
```

Comment: this is the right answer. 
btw you can also use `rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());`

Answer (score 0):

using xml - use `android:toDegrees="360"` instead of 1800

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<rotate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

By using code rotate an image

```
ImageView img_rotate = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_rotate);
rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
rotation.setFillAfter(true);
img_rotate.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Comment: it rotates continuously, but there is a pause between two rotations.I want it not to stop before starting another rotation. is that possible?

Comment: you need to set your own interpolation e.g. linear one to prevent this behaviour